Recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n+1}a_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n+1}a_n$
Let $a_0=0,\ a_1=1.$ For $0<\alpha<1,$ the sequence defined by the recurrence relation: $\ a_{n+1} = \alpha a_{n-1} + (1-\alpha) a_n\ \forall n\geq 1$ has a limit because it is just a geometric series with common ratio $-\alpha.$ But what if the ratio depends on $n$ like the following:
Let $a_0=0,\ a_1=1.$ Define the recurrence relation: $\ a_{n+1} = \frac{n}{n+1}a_{n-1} + \frac{1}{n+1} a_n\ \forall n\geq 1.$ That is, $a_{n+1}$ is $1/(n+1)$ of the way from $a_{n-1}$ towards $a_n.$ Drawing a sketch on a number line, clearly this sequence either has one limit point or two limit points.
[Yes, you can also write $\frac{n}{n+1}$ as $1-\frac{1}{n+1}.$]

Does this sequence have one limit point or two limit points (and how do you prove
this)?

I suspect the sequence has one limit. If this is the case, is there a closed form for $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n?$

Consider $b_n=\dfrac{a_n}{n!}$.

Inspired by Limit of sequence involving factorials: For $n \ge 1$ is
$$
\begin{align}
 (n+1)\cdot(a_{n+1}-a_n) &= - n \cdot(a_n - a_{n-1}) \\
 &= (-1)^2 \cdot(n-1)\cdot (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}) \\
 &= \cdots = (-1)^n \cdot 1 \cdot  (a_1 - a_0) \\
 &= (-1)^n  \, .
\end{align}
$$
It follows that
$$ 
a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}
$$
and that converges to $\ln(2)$.
